# StorageItemAccessList like functionality in Android

Tags: android, windows, storage

For windows, we have StorageItemAccessList  to get a token for a file that users opens,which helps us to access the same file in future using the same token and not care if the file was moved to other location. Do we have similar support in android? 
My requirement is that, i am saving list of files that user opened recently and if a file is deleted/moved to other location, need FutureAccessList token kind of functionality to handle the cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do we have similar support in android?

No, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Is there no way to get any such functionality? I do not have any idea where to start for custom implementation or if its even possible to do in an app.

Comment: @cruskal: "Is there no way to get any such functionality?" -- not really. You get a bit more isolation from filesystem "move" operations by working with `Uri` values and `ContentResolver`, such as via [the Storage Access Framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) on Android 4.4+.